# Floating Problem With Rigidbody.Velocity in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Below is the code that I am using to move an object in Unity. The `rb.Velocity` line makes my object float in in Gameplay mode. If I comment out the line then the object falls just fine.

Could someone explain whats happening here?

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float forwardVelocity = 0F;
    public float maxSpeed = 180;
    public float acceleratePerSecond = 8.0F;
    public float rotateSpeed = 3.0F;
    private float yaw = 0.0f;
    private float pitch = 0.0f;
    protected Rigidbody rb;
    float timeZeroToMax = 2.5F;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        acceleratePerSecond = maxSpeed / timeZeroToMax;
        forwardVelocity = 0F;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) //Accelerate The Vehicle
            {
                if (forwardVelocity< maxSpeed)
                {
                forwardVelocity += acceleratePerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

                }

            }


        forwardVelocity = Mathf.Min(forwardVelocity, maxSpeed);


        rb.velocity = transform.forward * forwardVelocity;


        transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed, 0);


        yaw += rotateSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");


        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform.forward` is a `Vector3(0,0,1)`, that's the problem.

You are setting your y velocity to 0.

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue, my object still takes a lot of time reaching the ground. It feels like it is floating, but actually it is moving very slowly down to the surface.

Comment: ok, that works for the falling part, but now its locking it's movement to the x axis only.

Comment: Nop mate, still locking in one direction only.

Comment: Now that's another problem, the question is to Y only, the other stuff you need to figure out yourself